# Weird error with setsockopt, "Protocol not available"

Tags: c, linux, sockets

The applicable code is below, as is the exact error.

```
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
if ( setsockopt( sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on) ) < 0 )
{
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
}
if ( setsockopt( sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_DF, &on, sizeof(on) ) < 0 )
{
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    printf("DF\n");
}
```

Error:

```
root@PC:~# gcc main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:71: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
root@PC:~# ./a.out localhost
Protocol not available
DF
```

It's odd that the second setsockopt is erroring, while the first one isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IP_DF` is a packet flag, not a socket option. Valid socket options are given in the `ip(7)` man page.

Comment: Read the ip(7) man page, I can't find how to set it to not defrag. Help?

Answer (score 0):

from ip(7) man page;

```
   IP_NODEFRAG (since Linux 2.6.36)
          If enabled (argument is nonzero), the reassembly of outgoing packets is
          disabled in the netfilter layer.  This option is only valid for
          SOCK_RAW sockets.  The argument is an integer.
```